# Can More Than One Tenant Read/Write a Contact?

Tags: salesforce, dynamics-crm, crm

I have a very basic requirement for a CRM I'm building in the Consumer Debt space.  An issuer, say Bank of America, has to charge off a credit card, so then send the credit card with the information to the collections department which can either farm it out to a collection agency, or sell the charged-off debt to another debt buying company.  While they're trying to collect the debt, they'll log bits of information about the customer: last address, are they working, did a collection company get involved.  That is, they'll collect information about the consumer behind the credit card.

Usually, the debt is passed on to a debt buyer who goes through this whole process again, usually with almost no information from BofA about the previous attempt to collect.

So here's the question: is there any capability in Microsoft CRM (or Salesforce) that would allow this customer record to be sold/transferred/shared between tenants?  The idea is that the consumer would be much better represented if their information flowed with the credit card as it made it's way through the debt buyers and collection agencies.

Comment: You could try exporting the data to XML and then importing to the other environment. Alternatively you could use a tool such as SSRS that could periodically run

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce has a feature called [Salesforce-to-Salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Salesforce_to_Salesforce) that does allow the sharing of data between two previously linked orgs.
You could also build your Managed Package that included web services/callouts to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamics 365 (formerly CRM) can import and export data effortlessly to/from Excel files.

I don't have a clue about Salesforce, but it's reasonable to believe it can too.

Answer (score 0):

To make the data interchange seamless between parties, there would have to be an industry standard way to describe a consumer credit collection profile.

For example, the finance industry has the FIX and FIXML protocols to describe trading transactions, and the publishing industry has the ONIX format for book metadata.

There appears to be something called the [Metro 2 format](http://www.cdiaonline.org/Metro2/content.cfm?ItemNumber=853) in the credit industry, but I'm not sure if it includes collections information.

If a standard format existed, ISV's could write add-ons for Dynamics 365 and SalesForce to import and export standardized profiles.